# mutliple war files getting deployed in wrong directory

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat, war

I am bundling multiple war files in a zip file for tomcat env using elastic beanstalk.
Instead of 'webapps' folder, the zip file is actually getting deployed inside 'webapps/ROOT' folder.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-tomcat-multiple-war-files.html

MyServices.zip

- service1.war
- ROOT.war

I would expect MyServices.zip to be deployed in '/usr/share/tomcat/webapps' folder, as per the documentation.
Instead, the zip file is copied to the ROOT directory as: '/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/MyServices.zip'

Is there a setting/config that needs to change to enable correct deployment?

I expect the zip file to be deployed in '/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/'
instead, it is copied in '/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/ROOT' directory